# Vhdl rising_edge statement not synthesizable

Tags: vhdl, frequency

I am writing a little program for use on my Zybo FPGA, its supposedly a variable frequency divider with 10 different steps.

However on the last line when I try to output my clock to an LED for testing purposes it gives me this error: Line 137: statement is not synthesizable since it does not hold its value under NOT(clock-edge) condition

Here is my code

```
entity StappenMotor is
Port (  Reset, CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
            X1, X2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
            Z1 : out STD_LOGIC);
end StappenMotor;

architecture Behavioral of StappenMotor is
signal speed : integer := 0;
signal puls : STD_LOGIC;
begin

speed_proc: process(X1, X2) is
begin
if (rising_edge(X1) and speed < 10) then
    speed <= speed + 1;
elsif (rising_edge(X2) and speed > 0) then
    speed <= speed - 1;
end if;
end process speed_proc;

freq_proc: process(CLK) is
variable int : integer := 0;
begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        int := int + 1;
    end if;

    case speed is
        when 0 =>
            if int = 250000000 then
                puls <= '1';
                int := 0;
            else puls <= '0';
            end if;
        when 1 =>
            if int = 200000000 then
                puls <= '1';
                int := 0;
            else puls <= '0';
            end if;
        when 2 =>
            if int = 175000000 then
                puls <= '1';
                int := 0;
            else puls <= '0';
            end if;
        when 3 =>
            if int = 150000000 then
                puls <= '1';
                int := 0;
            else puls <= '0';
            end if;
        when 4 =>
            if int = 125000000 then
                puls <= '1';
                int := 0;
            else puls <= '0';
            end if;
        when 5 =>
            if int = 100000000 then
                puls <= '1';
                int := 0;
            else puls <= '0';
            end if;
        when 6 =>
            if int = 75000000 then
                puls <= '1';
                int := 0;
            else puls <= '0';
            end if;
        when 7 => 
            if int = 62500000 then
                puls <= '1';
                int := 0;
            else puls <= '0';
            end if;
        when 8 =>
            if int = 50000000 then
                puls <= '1';
                int := 0;
            else puls <= '0';
            end if;
        when 9 =>
            if int = 35000000 then
                puls <= '1';
                int := 0;
            else puls <= '0';
            end if;
        when 10 =>
            if int = 25000000 then
                puls <= '1';
                int := 0;
            else puls <= '0';
            end if;
        when others =>
            if int = 10000000 then
                puls <= '1';
                int := 0;
            else puls <= '0';
            end if;
        end case;
    end process freq_proc;

test: process(puls) is
begin
    if rising_edge(puls) then
        Z1 <= '1';
    else Z1 <= '0';
    end if;
end process test;
end Behavioral;
```

Error occurs on the line:

```
if rising_edge(puls) then
```

Anyone got a clue?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your processes have some issues, though the compiler may not complain about them as loudly as the one in `test`.

In `speed_proc`, you are qualifying `rising_edge()` with an additional comparison. I would recommend nesting `if` statements instead (put the comparison `if` inside the `rising_edge()` `if`). You're also trying to clock the same register with 2 separate clocks. You probably need to find a different way to do this.

In `freq_proc`, only your variable increment is inside the `rising_edge()` check - I don't see a reason not to put the rest in as well. It's more standard, and it should generally lead to fewer unexpected problems.

In `test`, as @Chiggs mentioned, what you're trying to accomplish is invalid. If you want to toggle `Z1` every clock cycle, you can do:

```
if rising_edge(puls) then
  Z1 <= not Z1;
end if;
```

(For simulation, you'd need to initialize `Z1` to see a valid output.)

Comment: I had indeed quite a few warnings pop up after I solved my error, thanks for pointing these out! But would you care to explain how I am clocking the same register with 2 separate clocks? Which would be those two clocks then?..

Comment: `rising_edge(X1)` in one statement, `rising_edge(X2)` in the other. `X1` and `X2` are both being used as clocks to the same register.

Comment: Ah yes I figured, just tried implementing and the board did indeed refuse to do this haha. I'll find a workaround. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the whole `test` process, not just the single line you've mentioned.

```
test: process(puls) is
begin
    if rising_edge(puls) then
        Z1 <= '1';
    else Z1 <= '0';
    end if;
end process test;
```

If you think about what you've described here, you're asking to drive `Z1` high whenever there's a rising edge on the clock and drive it low whenever `puls` changes but isn't a rising edge (which includes Z->1, 1->0, Z->0 transitions).

This generally isn't possible in an FPGA and therefore is not synthesisable, hence the tool complaining.

Comment: The design will not give an infinitely small pulse on `Z1`, since evaluation of the process after the `rising_edge(pulse)` is postponed until next change on the `puls` signal due to the sensitivity list.  In simulation a `pulse` with values "010101" will actually output "010101" on `Z1`.  But the conclusion is anyway correct: The construction is typically not synthesizable, since the tools are not made to handle that kind of construction.

Comment: @MortenZilmer thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer to incorporate your comments.

Comment: Thanks both of you! I managed to get rid of the error by just swapping out the rising_edge with an if statement. No clue why I even went for a rising edge in the first place, appearently I dont even need its functionality.